# What's the difference between 支人 and 殖人？

Tags: internet-slang

It seems people always use these words to war up. They have same pronunciations, are they antonyms? I can't find them in any dictionary.

Comment: where do you see these terms?

Answer (score 4):

支人 is the abbreviation of 支那人. 支那 was originally India's ancient name for China, and was later used by Japan. It has now become a derogatory term, somewhat similar to calling a Japanese Jap. "支那人" is often used on the Internet by Chinese languges users who oppose the Chinese government, and it is used to refer to Chinese people who are too patriotic, similar to 小粉紅. For example, in Taiwan, the term of Mainland China is often called 支語. But in some times, this is a severely discriminatory term.

殖 in 殖人 mean 殖民(colonization), and 殖人 are those who support colonialism and colonialist countries. It is a derogatory term to describe Chinese people who tend to be liberal and close to Western culture. For the more patriotic Chinese, the colonizers do not identify with their own country, but are spiritually colonized by Western countries, similar to "Boba liberal".

支人 and 殖人 represent opposing positions in politics, which is why you mentioned that he was used to war up. To put it simply, for the 殖人, the 支人 blindly followed the Chinese government; for the 支人, the 殖人 blindly followed Western values.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In addition, 支人 and 殖人 are all internet slangs. So this is the reason why they cannot be found in dictionaries. Also, most of them are used to attack people who have different opinions, so they are always used by rude people and shouldn't be used by nice people.

Answer (score 1):

殖人 is literally a *colonizee*, someone who has been colonized. It is used to refer to Chinese people who are more liberal or more Western-facing/supporting.

支人 is a derogatory term to refer to Chinese people. It is usually used by overseas Chinese to talk about certain overly-patriotic Mainlanders. See: [Wiktionary | 支那人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%94%AF%E9%82%A3%E4%BA%BA)

Comment: They are more than liberal or more Western-facing/supporting. This term is usually referring to those who say *everything is good in the West*. For example: The train that derailed in the US showed that US citizens have the freedom to consume contaminated food!

Answer (score -3):

Yes, they have the same meaning.
殖人=The people's who like to be slave=支人